# Inputting values to a string as a website URL for the page to be downloaded

Tags: c#

I'm messing around with the System.Net library in C# and I'm trying to simply have it set up such that you enter an url and it will take that as a string and put that into the parameter for the URl in the Client.DownloadString() field.

Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
namespace StringDownloadTest
{
    class GetInformation
    {
        string EnterString;
        public string InputString()
        {
            EnterString = Console.ReadLine();
            return EnterString;
        }
    }

    class DownloadString
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetInformation R = new GetInformation();
            R.InputString();

            string downloadedString;
            System.Net.WebClient client;
            client = new System.Net.WebClient();
            downloadedString = client.DownloadString(R.InputString());
            Console.WriteLine("String: {0}", downloadedString);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help here, it will compile but the program crashes.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Too long to type out, here is a link to a screen cap. http://imgur.com/xoz5vK4

Comment: If you right click, choose mark, then highlight your error and right click again, it will put the text into your buffer whereby you can paste it here.  Just sayin. :)

Comment: What address are you inputting into the app? The error implies the address is not correctly formed.

Comment: See Romoku's answer. That should be the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `R.InputString` twice and only entering input for the first time.

Try:

```
GetInformation R = new GetInformation();
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid url protocol://domain");
var input = R.InputString();

Uri uri;
if(!Uri.TryCreate(input, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Url format could not be determined for {0}", input);
    Environment.Exit(1);
}

var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
var downloadedString = client.DownloadString(uri);
Console.WriteLine("String: {0}", downloadedString);
```